# Looking for the name of a method of wilderness navigation

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the *name* of the method of navigation or orienteering in which you sight a landmark in the distance, work your way toward it, and then repeat with another landmark further off?

Comment: I have occasionally done this in places that are perhaps not quite as remote as the OP had in mind. It is 'there's the Royal Oak'. When leaving, we climb a hill and say 'there's the Red Lion'. And thus we wend our weary way to our destination.

Answer (score 5):

*Orienteering* is perhaps the word you are looking for. I am told it means running between various checkpoints whose position is defined with greater or lesser precision, and where the runner is entitled to visit them in the order he pleases. I would, sad to say, have no first-hand experience of this.

Comment: Wictionary says orienteering uses a map and compass: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orienteering

Comment: Correct.  I should have made clear that I want the name of the method of navigation using *nothing but* distant landmarks, and no maps, compasses, or other aids.  --Claude.

Answer (score 4):

I've always heard that called simply *landmark navigation*.

Answer (score 1):

*Wayfinding* maybe? Seems like it might be too general and isn't a sport like orienteering.